# How to Travel in the EU with a UK 1951 Refugee Travel Document: Visa Requirements and Country List

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, eu, refugees

Could you please provide a list of European Union (EU) countries where individuals holding a UK 1951 Refugee Travel Document can travel without a visa? I am particularly interested in information about Poland and Moldova. I am already aware that the Netherlands, Belgium, and Croatia are among these countries. Are there any other EU member states with similar visa requirements? Thank you

Comment: I don’t think the UK publishes such a list, however you can check entry requirements via the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) website.